# java web start launch

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

I always receive a "unable to launch the application" while trying run a jnlp file, note that this file use an external JAR file. Please help me to fix this issue.

the is is contents of the JNLP file

```
<jnlp codebase="file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/WebSrv/My%20Documents/NetBeansProjects/Token2/dist/" href="launch.jnlp" spec="1.0+">
  <information>
    <title>Token2</title>
    <vendor>WebSrv</vendor>
    <homepage href=""/>
    <description>Token2</description>
    <description kind="short">Token2</description>
  </information>
  <update check="always"/>
  <security>
    <all-permissions/>
  </security>
  <resources>
    <j2se version="1.7+"/>
    <jar href="Token2.jar" main="true"/>
    <jar href="lib/freetts.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <application-desc main-class="token.SpeechAndVision"/>
</jnlp>
```

Comment: you need to provide more information about your error. The JWS launcher has several tabs of information when an error is thrown that are necessary to troubleshoot your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your jar may not be signed, can you provide more details on this? click on the details buttons on the error dialog .

Comment: which JAR file??
BTW, both JAR files have been signed by using the self-signed feature in Netbeans

Comment: You need to provide more info on this then. It could be anything from signing issues to version mismatch problem or may be even jnlp syntax issue. CLick on the 'DETAILS' button of the error dialog box .

Comment: self-signing is no longer supported for jnlp jars in Java 7 with medium and above security level set (set in ControlPanel).  Note also, that properties that are not properly prefixed will not be passed to the application unless the jnlp itself is signed.